# For a continuous function f with Dom(f)= [0,1) proof that for every $c>0$ there is an $a$ in $[0,1)$ such that $f(a)>c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

For a continuous function $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x \in(0,1)$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{⁡1}{f(x)}=0$$ 
I have to prove that for every $c>0$ there exists an $a \in [0,1)$ with $f(a)>c$.
Can anyone help me with this. Intuitively I understand but how to prove it nicely.

And how can I prove  that f([0,1))=[0,∞). Or can I just say that because f is continuous and strictly monotone and injective that this follows automatically?

Comment: Write out what $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{f(x)} = 0$ actually means: For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (1-\delta, 1), \frac{1}{f(x)} < \varepsilon$.  That means that $f(x) > \ldots$ what?

Comment: Please format with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}1/f(x)=0$ implies that for every $e\in R$, there exists $e'$ such that $1-x<e'$ implies that $1/f(x)<e$, take $e=1/c$, you have for $1-x<e'$, $1/f(x)<1/c$ this implies $f(x)>c$.

To use intermediate value theorem, you have $f(0)=0$, there exists $0<x<1-e'$ such that $f(x)>c$, the intermediate value theorem implies that there exists $y\in [0,x]$ such that $f(y)=c$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This question was a question which was in a part of my book where one of the topics was the intermediate value theorem. So I thought I have to use this theorem. Can it also solved by using that theorem?